# Reference type example questions

Tags: c++, reference-type

Let's say I have the following example program in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc , char** argv) {

int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int& aRef = a;
int& bRef = b;
aRef = bRef; // This just sets aRef to point to b?
aRef = 3; // Now aRef points to a new int 3 not stored in a other variable?
// a = 3 b = 2
bRef = 4;
// a = 3 b = 4
aRef = long(&bRef); // Why do we need long casting here?
bRef = 5;
// a: varying b = 5 // Why is a varying?
aRef = bRef;
bRef = 6;
// a = 5 b = 6 // Why a no more varying?

}
```

Could somebody explain it line by line and perhaps reveal errors? I have added comments to lines which are especially unclear to me.

Comment: Hint: you can't reassign a reference.  References are (can be thought of as) aliases and can never be changed once created.

Comment: I'd suggest to step through the program with the debugger; This should clarify a lot.

Comment: I will add that this line `aRef = long(&bRef);` is so strange I would go back and check the example sheet.  It does not fit with the other questions, and if I saw it in production code would cause me to raise a code-review to make sure I understood the author's intention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc , char** argv) {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int& aRef = a;         // aRef is now another name for a
    int& bRef = b;         // bRef is now another name for b
    aRef = bRef;           // same as a = b
    aRef = 3;              // same as a = 3
    bRef = 4;              // same as b = 4
    aRef = long(&bRef);    // &bRef is the same as &b - i.e. take address of b - stores address in a
    bRef = 5;              // same as b = 5
    aRef = bRef;           // same as a = b
    bRef = 6;              // same as b = 6

}
```

Comment: imho the answer should mention that `aRef = long(&bRef);` is strange and hides a loss in precision that is most likely an error that would be caught by the compiler if it was written as  `aRef = int(&bRef);` (or even better as `static_cast`)

Comment: @tobi As posted it's certainly not great code, and as you say may lose precision, but taking the address of a variable via a reference is not all that strange.

Comment: taking the address of a variable via a reference isnt the problem I was refering to, but storing the adress in an `int`

Comment: @tobi Ooh, I've seem _lots_ of code that does that :-(

Comment: Why is the cast to long used? So the address of bRef is taken and casted to a long and then stored in an int.

Comment: @mac This would be illegal `a = &b;` because there is no implicit conversion from pointers to ints. The C-style cast turns the pointer into an integer type, which can then be assigned to an int. As people have observed, you really, really do not want to write code like this.

Comment: @mac the problem is that the value stored in `a` is pretty useless, you wont be able to cast it back to an `int*` in any meaningful way. See [here](http://ideone.com/fork/2kzxvu) for an example